# git pull : error: preserve: 'preserve' superseded by 'merges' fatal: invalid value for 'pull.rebase': 'preserve'

Tags: git, ubuntu

I'm used to using git, and this is the first time I get this error that I don't understand.

After a fresh clone on Linux

```
# git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Even if I know that all is updated :

```
# git pull
error: preserve: 'preserve' superseded by 'merges'
fatal: invalid value for 'pull.rebase': 'preserve'
# 

# git --version
git version 2.37.1
#
```

Why this ?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Indeed I hardly see how it could be more descriptive. You have a bad value for `pull.rebase` in your gitconfig file, namely `preserve`. Fix it. "git version 2.37.1" Yup, that version is after the `preserve` value became illegal.

Comment: Thanks matt :) I will answer.
On Ubuntu, it's the version you get when you do a `# apt-get install git`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a `/etc/gitconfig` not linked to the git package, I can't know its origin
I removed it

```
[alias]
  sts = status -s
  st = status -sb
  cl = clone
  ci = commit
  ca = commit --amend
  filelog = log -u
  fl = log -u

  cp = cherry-pick
  co = checkout
  unstage = reset HEAD
  precommit = diff --cached --diff-algorithm=minimal -w

  pushf = push --force-with-lease

  br = branch
  bra = branch -ra

  #list commands
  tip = log -n 1 --abbrev-commit --decorate
  lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
  lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty='format:%C(auto)%h %C(cyan)[%ar]%C(auto)%d %C(yellow)%ae %Creset%s' --abbrev-commit --all
  tig = log --graph --boundary --left-right --cherry-pick --decorate HEAD...FETCH_HEAD
  ll = log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --numstat

  #list all aliases
  la = "!git config -l | grep alias | cut -c 7-"
  #list modified files in last commit
  dl = "!git ll -1"

  #diff last commit
  dlc = diff --cached HEAD^
  dr  = "!f() { git diff -w "$1"^.."$1"; }; f"
  diffr  = "!f() { git diff "$1"^.."$1"; }; f"
  dw = diff --word-diff
  dcw = diff --color-words
  dcwr = diff --color-word=.

  r = reset
  r1 = reset HEAD^
  r2 = reset HEAD^^
  rh = reset --hard
  rh1 = reset HEAD^ --hard
  rh2 = reset HEAD^^ --hard
  nevermind = !git reset --hard HEAD && git clean -d -f

  #stash
  sl = stash list
  stashes = stash list
  sa = stash apply
  ss = stash save
  sp = stash pop

  last = log -1 --stat
  lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %Cblue<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=re
lative --all

[merge]
  tool = kdiff3

[mergetool "kdiff3"]
  trustExitCode = False

[diff]
  guitool = kdiff3

[difftool "kdiff3"]
  trustExitCode = False

[core]
  autocrlf = input
  trustctime = false
  editor = vim
  filemode = false
  eof = lf
[push]
  default = upstream
[pull]
  rebase = preserve

[credential]
  helper = cache --timeout 36000
```

Comment: `/etc/gitconfig` is the system-level fallback global. Your answer does not actually differ from what I already told you: you have a gitconfig that has `[pull] rebase = preserve` and that name, `preserve`, is now illegal. I didn't say in my response _which_ gitconfig was to blame because I can't see your computer; knowing that is your problem.

Comment: Since `/etc/gitconfig` does not belong to any package, and since here developers are used to handling their own config, this file is not important at all. For example, it does not exist on centos/redhat.

Answer (score 6):

Try `git config --list --show-origin --show-scope`

In ubuntu 22.04 a newer version of git deprecated "pull.rebase=preserve"

Git typically has config:

- system level in `/etc/gitconfig`
- global level in `/home/<username>/.gitconfig`
- local level in `.git/config` of the repo you are in

I suspect the repo you are in has the old settings so you can run:

`git config --local pull.rebase merges`

or if you see it in system or global modify the above command to the correct scope.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.